# hide "Open in New Tab" checkbox in link field

Tags: php, custom-field, views

I added a custom field to a repeater with PHP:

```
        [
            'key' => 'field_sponsor_badge_url',
            'name' => 'url',
            'label' => 'URL',
            'type' => 'link',
        ],
```

due to the fact that it is a link field, when a user clicks it, a popup window shows with a checkbox for open link in new tab:
[image]

how do I hide this little subfield by adding a new entry to the array that creates the field?

And not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821028/remove-open-link-in-a-new-window-tab-checkbox-in-post-link-visual-editor because I am only trying to hide the checkbox for this particular link field, that solution will hide all of them everywhere. I am not trying to hide all of those checkboxes for every link field on the page either.

Comment: That dialog box is built-in to WordPress and is functionally unrelated to ACF. I'd remove the part about ACF as it's unrelated to the question, and could be flagged as off-topic, since third-party plugin support is off-topic here.

Comment: ok thanks yeah I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Site-Wide Checkbox Hide

You can add a simple function to your `functions.php` to change its visibility (and will also set the default checked state to `false`):

```
function disable_open_new_window() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('input#link-target-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $('#wp-link .link-target').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action ('after_wp_tiny_mce', 'disable_open_new_window');
```

This will change the visibility of that checkbox site-wide, however, as the dialog box is not specific to ACF, and is used a few places in WordPress.

Reference: [Prevent WordPress Authors From Setting Links to Open in New Windows](https://www.geekwire.com/devblog/prevent-wordpress-authors-from-setting-links-to-open-in-a-new-window/)

### Field-Specific Checkbox Hide

As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible, since the dialog box isn't specific to custom fields (or ACF), it's a WordPress built-in dialog box.

Instead of hiding the checkbox, you can make it functionally useless instead. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/), you'll see you can retrieve a `$link['target']` option, which you can choose to use, or set that field to `_self` or `_blank` or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: If you want to be even more WordPress-y, put the JS in its own file, then use the `enqueue_script()` function to load it.

Comment: That is almost the solution but that is going to hide the checkbox everywhere on the whole site, I only want to hide it on one edit screen for one page only when this field is rendered

Comment: @steve8094 Like only when you're using the link ACF field?

Comment: yes, I'm just trying to have this specific field render without that option. Is there maybe something I can add to that array?

Comment: @steve8094 No, there's no options in ACF for disabling that checkbox (through code or otherwise). I don't believe what you're asking for is possible, as the dialog box is built into WordPress, and all ACF is doing is showing the dialog box, and then retrieving information from it.

Comment: Instead of hiding the checkbox, you can make it functionally useless instead. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/), you'll see you can retrieve a `$link['target']` option, which you can choose to use, or set that field to `_self` or `_blank` or whatever you want it to be.